# Getting reference to collection inside foreach binding without knowing name

Tags: knockout.js

Given the following example, I am passing the parent collection (`source: $parent.myThing.children`) into the custom binding. I was wondering is there anything on a context that tells me what the parent collection is without knowing the name?

```
<div data-bind="foreach: myThing.children">
    <button data-bind="arrayMoveUp: { item: $data, source: $parent.myThing.children }">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i> Up
    </button>
    <button data-bind="arrayMoveDown: { item: $data, source: $parent.myThing.children }">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i> Down
    </button>
</div>
```

for example i'd like to be able to do something like `source: $source` which would then pass what the foreach is bound to.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's accessible by default. You can create a custom extended `foreach` binding that adds it to the `bindingContext` though...

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.customForEach = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    ko.utils.extend(bindingContext, {
      '$arraySource': ko.unwrap(valueAccessor())
    });

    return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init.apply(null, arguments);
  },
  update: function() {
    return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update.apply(null, arguments);
  }
};


ko.applyBindings({
  items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="customForEach: items">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: $arraySource[$index() - 1]"></span> -
    <strong data-bind="text: $data"></strong> -
    <span data-bind="text: $arraySource[$index() + 1]"></span> -
  </li>
</ul>
```